# What is the origin of "acorn"?

Tags: etymology

I am from the Dutch-speaking part of Belgium, and this popped into my head today. Is the word *acorn* (the nut of an oak tree) in any way related to the Dutch word for squirrel, *eekhoorn*, the animal that collects acorns for food?

Looking at *eekhoorn*, one will have a hard time finding any logical meaning to the naming of this animal. There's *eek*, which is not a Dutch word, and *hoorn* which means *horn*. So it doesn't make much sense.  But the pronunciation even in Dutch/Flemish is remarkably equal to the English *acorn*.

Since many words have migrated country borders (like the NL *bolwerk* and EN *bulwark*), I wouldn't be surprised if it's the same with *acorn*/*eekhoorn*, except for the fact that *eekhoorn* is the actual animal that consumes the acorns. That would make it pretty unique, I think.

By the way, *acorn* in Dutch is *eikel*, having different connotations which I won't explain here.

Comment: Sadly not: see the etymology of *acorn* at [Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=acorn&searchmode=none)

Comment: @MattЭллен, but what's the etymology of the Dutch squirrel? hoorn-horn could be a coincidence, and if æcern meant nut, and squirrels are nut-eaters...

Comment: He did answer my question in a way (the english etymology part).   Unfortunately the Dutch Language SE is currently in definition phase.

Comment: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Germanic/aikwernô#Proto-Germanic) says that *eekhoorn* comes from proto-Germanic *aikwernô*. The proto-Germanic word for *oak* is *aiks*. So maybe *eekhoorns* have *oak* in their etymology, just like *acorns*. (Does anybody know what the *wernô* might have come from?)

Comment: The etymology of *eekhoorn* is uncertain beyond Proto-Germanic: http://gtb.inl.nl/iWNTLINKS/DATADIR/paginazy.html?EWN+/iWDB/search?actie=article_content&wdb=EWN&id=ewn003731 There may or may not be connections with other words and stems. The word *acorn* does not appear to be related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually an interesting question.  The OED provides this tale:

> **Etymology:** The formal history of this word has been much
>   perverted by ‘popular etymology.’ OE. *æcern* neut., pl.
>   *æcernu*, is cogn. w. ONor. *akarn* neut. (Dan. *agern*,
>   Norw. *aakorn*), Dutch *aker* ‘acorn,’ OHG. *ackeran*
>   masc. and neut. (mod.G. *ecker*, pl. *eckern*) ‘oak or
>   beech mast,’ Goth. *akran* ‘fruit,’ prob. a deriv. of Goth.
>   *akr-s*, ONor. *akr*, OE. *æcer* ‘field,’ orig. ‘open
>   unenclosed country, the plain.’
>
> Hence *akran* appears to have
>   been originally ‘fruit of the unenclosed land, natural produce of
>   the forest,’ mast of oak, beech, etc., as in HG., extended in Gothic
>   to ‘fruit’ generally, and gradually confined in Low G., Scand., and
>   Eng., to the most important forest produce, the mast of the oak.
>   (See Grimm, under *Ackeran* and *Ecker*.) In Ælfric’s
>   *Genesis* xliv. 11, it had perhaps still the wider sense, a
>   reminiscence of which also remains in the ME. *akernes of okes*.
>
> Along with this restriction of application, there arose a tendency
>   to find in the name some connexion with *oak*, OE. *ác*,
>   north. *ake*, *aik*. Hence the 15th and 16th c. refashionings
>   *ake-corn*, *oke-corn*, *ake-horn*, *oke-horn*,
>   with many pseudo-etymological and imperfectly phonetic variants.
>   Of these the 17th c. literary *acron* seems to simulate the
>   Gr. ἄκρον top, point, peak.
>
> The normal mod. repr. of OE.
>   *æcern* would be *akern*, *akren*, or ? *atchern*
>   as already in 4; the actual *acorn* is due to the 16th c. fancy
>   that the word *corn* formed part of the name.